# JavaScript RegExp: match, but don't capture

Tags: javascript, regex

There are a thousand regular expression questions on SO, so I apologize if this is already covered. I did look first.

Given the following pattern:

```
(?:/|-)[0-9]{2}$
```

And the following strings:

```
str1 = '65/65/65'
str2 = '65/65/6565'
```

The matches are:

```
str1 = '/65' // expected '65'
str2 = ''    // as I expected
```

My intention with **?:** was to match, but not include a **/** or **-**. What is the correct regular expression to meet my expectations?

Comment: Doesn't look like a valid regex to me, you probably should escape the `/` ?

Comment: @adeneo it's a valid regex when it is used within `"`

Comment: Use `[\/-]([0-9]{2})$` and grab matched group #1

Comment: [See this demo](http://regex101.com/r/iC9yT4/1)

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html

Comment: Here we go again, the old **no lookbehind** in JS.

Comment: anubhava, adeneo, and Jonny 5, awesome!

Comment: This regex also do the job `(?=[-\/](\d{2})$)`

Comment: @sln why it fails to match -5 in the first string? regex101.com/r/lC5sI6/3 ?  Mat i know the reason?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Well, its not supposed to match `-5` because there is no `-` in your regex. And of course there is only a single digit `5` when the regex is looking for `\d{2}`

Comment: @sln i put the both `\d`, `-` inside a character class.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I took the `-` out as I posted in your deleted answer as its functional equivalent `\b\d{2}$`. In reality `-` had nothing to do with it, you were just testing the word boundry right ?

Comment: yep, i agree so that i deleted my answer.My statement to this `To me it looks like (?!\/|-) will always match because you specify \d as the next character which is not [/-]`, is it isn't true. If your statement is true then why `-5` fails to match in this demo http://regex101.com/r/lC5sI6/3

Comment: @AvinashRaj  - Think of it as a singularity. If I say the next character can't be `X` then match `Y`, why do I need to check that Y is not X when they are constant ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I know you had [\d-] in a class, but `-5` doesn't match because `(?!\/|-)[\d-]` says _not_ `/` nor `-`. So, the regex reduces to `\d` which doesn't match '-5' in its entirety.

Comment: Finally i win. That's what i said 11 hours before. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As there's no lookbehind available in Javascript, just wrap the desired part into a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
var str =  '65/66/67';

if(res = str.match(/(?:\/|-)([0-9]{2})$/)) {
  console.log(res[1]);
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLfz4fLm/)

Note: `(?:\/|-)` can be replaced with a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[\/-]` like @anubhava commented.

Comment: +1 this is indeed the best (simplest) solution in JS.

Comment: happy you like it anubhava :)

Comment: Agh -- you hit all my points before I submitted my answer! Nice work Jonny

Answer (score 2):

Normally, this would be done with a lookbehind:

```
/(?<=[-\/])[0-9]{2}$/
```

Sadly, JavaScript doesn't support those.

Instead, since you know the length of the "extra bit" (ie. one character, either `-` or `/`), it should be simple enough to just `.substr(1)` it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no look behind, but there is exclusive matching (`?:`) as it won't fail.  The issue is that it will be included as part of the overall match (index `0` of the result).  Therefore the best alternative is to instead capture the portion you do want.  In your example this could be done by surrounding the digit matching in parentheses.

```
var re   = /(?:[/-])([0-9]{2})$/,
    str1 = '12/34/56',
    str2 = '12/34/5678';

var res1 = str1.match(re);  // will want to use res1[1], not res1[0]  
var res2 = str2.match(re);  // null returned
```

Comment: `(?:...)` is called non-capturing group. Haven't heard of the term exclusive matching.

Comment: @nhahtdh you are correct. Exclusive matching is how I refer to it mainly because it rolls off the tongue easier and is not incorrect that matches are excluded from the result.  I don't think I said that it was the technical term - the parenthetical inclusion was only to clarify and support what I was referencing. I wouldn't use parentheses if I called it a non-capturing group. In any case, it'd probably be better to use the standard reference, but sometimes I like to be a little different. Also, for perspective, in French it is not called "non-capturing group" :)